# Sorting an array based on calculated values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

For a recent java coding test I had a question similar to the following:

A function receives a string of comma separated values.
Add the digits of each number contained to create a single value for that number.
Order these in ascending order
Return the original values (ie not the calculated ones) in this sorted order.

Hence if the string input is:

{"91,15,20"}
The digits after adding would be: 
10, 6, 2
since (9+1 == 10, 1+5 == 6, 2+0 == 2)

After sorting into ascending order:
2,6,10

We would thus return the original string sorted as above as as:
20,15,91

From a coding perspective this means we would split the string on the comma into a string array

For each item, convert the string to an int and then calculate its 'value'

Now, this is where I'm foxed!

At first I added the calculated item to an array list and then sorted it but realised that since I needed to return the original strings (not the calculated values), this was no good.

As such I'm looking for advise for future knowledge.

I don't actually specifically want code but more so advice on the approach.

Would using a map have been the best way? I contemplated that but can't see how that work, especially if there could be duplicate values in the string.
Would it have been better to have two arrays?
Is it best to sort as I parse the string array?

Although I've failed that question I want to still complete it so that I'll know.. I need to learn from failure after all.

Would be grateful for advice in the best approach please.

Comment: You might consider some kind of `SortingContainer` class that had a `sortingKey` and a `value`.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more. I wonder if the following approach would be good, though it seems a bit heavy. Create an object that holds a pair of the original value and the calculated value. Add these objects to a list and then use a comparator to sort them. Is that a sensible approach or is it over the top?

Comment: You don't need to create a new object. Just put the logic inside the comparator. See my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some advice. I assume you are using Java 8.

Instead of putting your values in a data structure like a map or something, why not discarding them after the calculation, if you don't care about performance?

Since JDK 1.8, there is this `sort` method on `ArrayList` that accepts a comparator. A `Comparator<Integer>` has this method:

```
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    
}
```

If you just fill in this method with something like this...

```
public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    Integer a = // add up the digits in o1
    Integer b = // add up the digits in o2
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

The sort will work! You can then prettify your code by turning this into a lambda:

```
list.sort(
        (o1, o2) -> {
                Integer a = <calculation>;
                Integer b = <calculation>;
                return a.compareTo(b);
        }
);
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using 1.7 rather than 1.8 but I can see the logic in what you're saying and how I can do that in 1.7

Comment: Rather than going through and calculating all the values, do it within the comparator which will use the result to do the sort. Your answer of course is a very good reason for me to move and learn what's new in 8! Thank you for your advice! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Shouldn't you return a.compareTo(b) in the lambda expression?